# Xcode autocomplete/suggestion box not showing relative to current line

Tags: swift, xcode

I am started using XCode and for some reason my autocomplete/suggestion box not showing below the current line of code as expected.
I can change the location and size with my mouse and maybe after changing it by mistake it's stuck but I didn't found any "change to default" settings or other people reporting about this issue.

Image from my editor you can see there the box is always shown in this location

[image: Image from my editor you can see there the box is always shown in this location]

Comment: Someone helped me. For other I am adding the solution here:
try restarting xcode
compltely
and also if it doesnt fix it try to delete your archives and user data
Xcode -> preferences -> Locations - > delete derived data and archives

Answer (score 0):

Someone helped me the solution was:
try restarting Xcode
completely
and also if it doesn't fix it try to delete your archives and user data
Xcode -> preferences -> Locations - > delete derived data and archives

My Fix Was:
Exit Xcode totally then delete derived data and archives